# css - Input radio button to target outter label when checked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, forms

I have the following code which I found on codepen and works and looks great!

```css
.switch-field {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 36px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.switch-field input {
    position: absolute !important;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.switch-field label {
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    margin-right: -1px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.switch-field label:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.switch-field input:checked + label {
    background-color: #a5dc86;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.switch-field label:first-of-type {
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.switch-field label:last-of-type {
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
    <div class="switch-field">
        <input type="radio" id="radio-three" name="switch-two" value="yes" checked/>
        <label for="radio-three">One</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio-four" name="switch-two" value="maybe" />
        <label for="radio-four">Two</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio-five" name="switch-two" value="no" />
        <label for="radio-five">Three</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

But unfortunately my generated HTML is laid out as follows (with the input inside the label):

```
<form class="form">
    <div class="switch-field">
        <label for="radio-three">
      <input type="radio" id="radio-three" name="switch-two" value="yes" checked/>
    One</label> 
        <label for="radio-four">
      <input type="radio" id="radio-four" name="switch-two" value="maybe" />
    Two</label>
        <label for="radio-five">
      <input type="radio" id="radio-five" name="switch-two" value="no" />
    Three</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

I am wondering if its possible just with CSS to adapt this class to make it work or if JS is necessary.

```
.switch-field input:checked + label {
background-color: #a5dc86;
box-shadow: none;
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: when you use + combinator in css that means the element immediately after the element. Since label is before the input field in your html. This css won't work.

Comment: There are two possible solution. First: change your HTML and put label after input field. Second to achieve your functionality through js

Comment: Yes the input is contained within the label. Is there any CSS that will work? Or will it be a matter for JS? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can't change the HTML then Js is the only option

Comment: Yes I thought so, its a matter of JS right? As im unable to change the HTML (its generated).

Comment: @JimWids see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71122939/2813224)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use JS.

When input element is inside the label then we do not need id on the element and 'for' attribute on the label, but when it is outside we need it.

```
<label>
  Foo
  <input name="foo" type="checkbox" />
</label>
```

Based on your HTML Code, To alter the styling of the label, would require a selector that affected the parent, which currently isn't possible.
Why? https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/

```
<input id="foo" name="foo" type="checkbox" />
<label for="foo">Foo</label>
```

So, to select the label of the :checked input, we need the label to be adjacent, not the parent.

**But in your code, HTML's label and input is implicit connecting. So I think the solution is to use JS.**

```js
let form = document.querySelector("form");

form.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  let target = event.target;
  let targetParent = target.parentElement;

  if (
    target.type === "radio" &&
    targetParent &&
    targetParent.tagName.toLowerCase() === "label"
  ) {
    let prior = form.querySelector('label.checked input[name="' + target.name + '"]');
    if (prior) {
      prior.parentElement.classList.remove("checked");
    }
    targetParent.classList.add("checked");
  }
}, false);
```

```css
.switch-field {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 36px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.switch-field input {
  position: absolute !important;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.switch-field label {
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  margin-right: -1px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.switch-field label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.switch-field label.checked {
  background-color: #a5dc86;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.switch-field label:first-of-type {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.switch-field label:last-of-type {
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <div class="switch-field">
    <label class="checked">
      <input type="radio" name="switch-two" value="yes" checked />
      One
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="switch-two" value="maybe" />
      Two
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="switch-two" value="no" />
      Three
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

### The Only CSS Solution Possible

The pseudo-selector [`:focus-within`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus-within/). Should an element have any children element that has focus, that parent will have styles applied to it. So a radio button that the user checks will trigger a focus event and in doing so activate the CSS ruleset that has `:focus-within` which is the label in the following example.

```css
.switch-field label:focus-within {
  background-color: #a5dc86;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <div class="switch-field">
    <label for="radio-three">
      <input type="radio" id="radio-three" name="switch-two" value="yes" checked/>
    One</label>
    <label for="radio-four">
      <input type="radio" id="radio-four" name="switch-two" value="maybe" />
    Two</label>
    <label for="radio-five">
      <input type="radio" id="radio-five" name="switch-two" value="no" />
    Three</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I was unaware of this pseudo-selector! Thanks for that!

Comment: Click on the label and click on another empty screen. Is that style still applied?

Comment: Thanks but yes Kyunjune Kim its not still applied when focus is away from this element.

Comment: Persistance of state wasn't a requirement, this is the only CSS solution involving an anscestor tag being affected by a child tag. Update your question to reflect that.

Comment: There are are ways to persist in a state using only CSS but that involves anchors.

Answer (score 1):

Here is example of how you can achieve desired functionality through javascript

```js
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]");
var labels = document.querySelectorAll("label");
labels[0].classList.add("checkedLabel");

checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    Array.from(labels).forEach(function(el) {
      el.classList.remove('checkedLabel');
    });
    this.parentElement.classList.add("checkedLabel");
  })
})
```

```css
.checkedLabel {
  background-color: #a5dc86;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <div class="switch-field">
    <label for="radio-three">
      <input type="radio" id="radio-three" name="switch-two" value="yes" checked/>
    One</label>
    <label for="radio-four">
      <input type="radio" id="radio-four" name="switch-two" value="maybe" />
    Two</label>
    <label for="radio-five">
      <input type="radio" id="radio-five" name="switch-two" value="no" />
    Three</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, replace `.switch-field input` with `.switch-field label input`.

A selector of the form `x1 x2 x3 ... xn—1 xn` (space separated) means `xn` which is a descendent of `xn−1` and so on.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply and help! Im so sorry to say it didnt work though https://codepen.io/jimbobstrawhat/pen/wvPrpJb Once again many thanks!

Comment: The selection works fine, as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/o3rks4wj/13/ .
You don't get the desired results due to other issues.